how to select column name which is not allowed to be in group by clause?
I have basic knowledge in sql, hope someone can explain me following: I have the following sql query:
 select
         f001,
         valid1,
         encid1,
         sum(val004) as AMOUNT#221,
         conid1,
         acc206
     from
         (
             select
                 f001,
                 encid1,
                 acc206,
                 valid1,
                 val004,
                 conid1
             from
                 table_tmp 
             where
                     valid2 = 4 and acc206=0 -- for EUR 
         ) table1
     group by
         f001,
        
         conid1,
         valid1,
         acc206
 ) table2

wehen I run the error msg:  00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression". This happens because I have encid1 in the select clause but not in group by clause. When I add it in group by  the erro msg disappear but we don't want to group by encid1. Now when I remove encid1 from select clause, I dont have possibility to join the result with other tables using encid1. any idea how to solve this?

I am using oracle

One column missing in the GROUP BY. (A selected column, not argument to aggregation function.)

@jarlh I know I have explained this. Problem is that we are not allowed to group by that missing column which is in this case encid1

Sorry, didn't read carefully. You can perhaps have that column as argument to aggregation function? (Depending on data and requirements.)

For each group, there can be multiple values for the column encid1. Oracle is saying.: "Which one do you want?" The max, the min, the avg, the concatenation, etc.

It would be helpful if you provided a minimal reproducible example. Some sample data (ddl, dml - not screenshots but real scripts) and what you are trying to get as output.

just wrap it in aggregation: MAX(encid1). Or some other aggregation logic. But you have to aggregate and pick only one value somehow if you don't group by it.

Either include it in the GROUP BY:
SELECT f001,
       valid1,
       encid1,
       SUM(val004) AS AMOUNT#221,
       conid1,
       acc206
from   table_tmp 
where  valid2 = 4
and    acc206 = 0 -- for EUR 
group by
       f001,
       valid1,
       encid1,
       conid1,
       acc206

Else aggregate the encid1 column:
SELECT f001,
       valid1,
       MIN(encid1) AS min_encid1,
       MAX(encid1) AS max_encid1,
       LISTAGG(encid1, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY encid1) AS list_of_encid1,
       SUM(val004) AS AMOUNT#221,
       conid1,
       acc206
from   table_tmp 
where  valid2 = 4
and    acc206 = 0 -- for EUR 
group by
       f001,
       valid1,
       conid1,
       acc206

